# lazy loading image in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to lazy load image for my incoming data, The hurdle is I have to display data along with the photo

**Scenario**:
along with my data I receive an Id and I have to call a function that get Image from the requested UR and format of image is base64

**test 1 case**

*note its just an example data is dynamic

```
<div ng-repeat="data in Data">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data.photo}}" ng-init="callBackendImage(data.id)">
            <!--I want to call this function everytime to get image-->
            <!--reponse if image is {name:'xyz',image:'base64string'-->

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <td style="vertical-align: top;min-width: 35px;">
                <span><b>{{data.location}}</b></span>
            </td>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.callBackendImage= function (id, data) {
        console.log('caled')
        console.log(id)
        $rootScope.showPreloader = true;
        awtcDataService.getRequest(id).then(function (_response) {
            console.log(_response)
            var res = _response
            if(res.data.success) {
                data.photo = res.data.image//getting base64 string                }
            console.log(data)
            // else {
            //     ctrl.errorCallBack =  true
            //     ctrl.errorFunction =  3
            // }
            $rootScope.showPreloader = false;

        })
```

Problem with above code:

The function is called and i get my image if data is too long there will be a lot of request to back-end , i want to call this function with id only when its available on view port or in container in other words on scroll call this function with id callBackendImage(data)

any help will be greatly apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe on `windows.onscroll` event. And when particular `data in Data` will be visible on screen(`x.offsetTop <= window.scrollY + window.innerHeight`), you should call `callBackendImage` with subsequent `awtcDataService.getRequest` invocation, otherwise `data.photo` should not be loaded and visible (`<img ng-show='data.photo' ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data.photo}}" />`):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.Data = [];
  $scope.loaded = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    $scope.Data[i] = {
      name: 'Name' + i
    };
    
  //just stub
  $scope.callBackendImage = function(id){        
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.Data[id].photo = id;        
        $scope.loaded++;
    }, 1000 + 2000 * Math.random());
  }

  function ProcessVisible() {
    var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('photos'));
    var visible = elements.filter(function(x) {
      return x.offsetTop < window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
    })

    for (var item of visible){
      var temp = $scope.Data[item.id];
      if (!temp.loading){        
          temp.loading = true;
          $scope.callBackendImage(item.id)                  
      }
    }
  }

  window.onscroll = ProcessVisible;
  $timeout(ProcessVisible, 100);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl' id='root'>
  Loaded {{loaded}} of {{Data.length}}
  <ul>
    <li class='photos' ng-style='{"background-color": data.photo ? "#acffac": "white"}' ng-repeat='data in Data' id='{{$index}}'>{{data.name}}: {{data.photo}}</li>
  <ul>
<div>
```